# Generate a strong type designer.cs file

Tags: c#, webforms

When using "Convert to Web Application" function in VS2010 Web Express, it does generate a corresponding designer.cs file.

However, the property declaration for user control are all using "System.Web.UI.UserControl", which means in the code behind file, the custom property or method in the custom user control cannot be used.

This can be solved by manually change the type in designer file, but I have a lot pages, so is there a better way to make the VS can do this automatically when it generate the designer.cs file?

thanks~

Comment: You created user controls that have the same name as the base .net controls?  Or are you saying you extended the existing controls?

Comment: It has a unique name (for ascx file, "MyControl" for example), but .net will automatically generate another name (for the class name "Control_MyControl"). And it extends from UserControl which is a .net base class. When the designer.cs file been generated, what I expect from the designer.cs is there should be a line `protected Control_MyControl myControl` instead of `protected UserControl myControl`...

Comment: which I have to manually update it so I can use properties and methods defined in Control_MyControl class...